# How to Select Unchecked Checkboxes but Not Indeterminate State Ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

My list of checkboxes consists of checked, unchecked, and indeterminate (3rd) state. For those who are wondering, I'm using jQuery to set indeterminate state for some checkboxes. At the end, I would like to find and select all of checkboxes with the unchecked state but not the indeterminate state with the use of jQuery.

Here are my checkboxes

```
<div id="list">
    <input id="item-1" type="checkbox">
    <input id="item-2" type="checkbox">
    <input id="item-3" type="checkbox"> 
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

I can get the checked ones with the following

```
var checkedItems = $("#list").find("input:checkbox:checked");
```

I can also get all the unchecked with the following

```
var uncheckedItems = $("#list").find("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
```

However, `uncheckedItems` will return me items that have indetermine state as well.

I've tried the following as well but I got `unsupported pseudo: indeterminate(…)`

```
var uncheckedItems = $("#list").find("input:checkbox:not(:checked):not(:indeterminate)");
```

So how do I only select unchecked items without selecting indeterminate ones?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that the symantec for checkboxes is on or off, a third state being neither expected or really supported.  Why not radio buttons with Yes / No / Not sure or something similarly easy to handle and understand?

Comment: Hi @JECarterII, unfortunately radio buttons don't work with our current UI. So we are stuck with checkboxes.

Comment: May I just ask how they "do not work"? Is it that you can't have multiple radio-buttons, because there is no room? Because looks-wise, there is no difference between checkboxes and radiobuttons, as long as they're styled the same.

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a js fiddle and more exact semantics to your use case. And add jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi @junkfoodjunkie, it doesn't work because of space, which affects the looks as well. In short, each checkbox represents a collection. If all items are in that collection, then show a check. If not all items are in it, show indeterminate. No item in that collection, do not check.

Comment: Why not just use a "traffic-light"-system? Green: all there, Yellow: some there, Red: none found? Could be used with just background-color, or as a circle-icon where the checkbox is now? I dunno - using "indeterminate" is a foreign concept for most users, as the standard function for the checkbox is either on or off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter on the indeterminate property

```
$("[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)")
  .filter(function () { return !this.indeterminate; });
```

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woe8ft1z/)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I came across it so thought I would update.  Instead of using a separate function under a filter as Victory suggested, this could be handled with simply extending the selector as thus:

```
$("[type=checkbox]:not(:checked):not(:indeterminate)")
```

[Modifed JSFiddle from Victory's answer here](https://jsfiddle.net/dracos85/xprcaodb/)